# Rx.js, Chrome Messaging API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, rxjs

After another part of the extension has sent a message using this code

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});
```

Any Rx.js experts out there who can take this messaging API

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

and wrap it in an Observable that emits new messages and allows a sendResponse?

Simply emitting incoming messages as an Observable is very easy.

```
const MessagingObservable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {      
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listener);
  function listener(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    observer.next(request); 
  }
  return () => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(listener);
  };
});
```

But how to bind the sendResponse callback?

Comment: It emits when a message has been received, as I'm sure you know. In the code you have information about the message (request) and the sender. It's more of an  rx.js question than a Chrome Extension API question. I can create an Observable that emits the messages but I don't know how to bind the sendResponse callback.

Comment: Just a guess: send `{request, sendResponse}` object to your observer and add `return true` in the listener to keep the messaging channel open. Optionally, if the observer can return the status immediately (not a Promise, but a simple true/false), you can use it to decide if `return true` is needed.

Comment: OK, worth a try!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built-in `fromEventPattern` function to create an observable, like this:

```js
const messages = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
  handler => chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handler),
  handler => chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(handler),
  (request, sender, sendResponse) => ({ request, sender, sendResponse })
);
```

Note that the call to `fromEventPattern` includes a result selector, so that values emitted by the observable contain the `request`, the `sender`, and the `sendResponse`, which you'd use like this:

```js
messages.subscribe(({ request, sender, sendResponse }) => {
  console.log(request);
  sendResponse(/* ... whatever ... */);
});
```

To support calling `sendResponse` asynchronously, the listener needs to be able to return `true`. This can be done by wrapping the `handler`, like this:

```js
const messages = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
  handler => {
    const wrapper = (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
      const event = { async: false, request, sender, sendResponse };
      handler(event);
      return event.async;
    };
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(wrapper);
    return wrapper;
  },
  (handler, wrapper) => chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(wrapper)
);
```

And you'd use it like this:

```js
messages.subscribe(event => {
  console.log(event.request);
  event.async = true;
  setTimeout(() => event.sendResponse(/* ... whatever ... */), 1000);
});
```

Comment: That is exactly right. Thanks very much. So many functions and operators in rx.js, I  suspected there would be a way to do this but had never come across fromEventPattern before.

Comment: Incidentally, I have another outstanding question in the same area, which you may also be able to solve with ease. If you're collecting points... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928351/rx-js-handling-chrome-extension-webrequest-api-callback-functions?rq=1

Comment: Actually, there's a complication here, which is also the problem I had with the other issue linked above. As pointed out in the comments to the original question, when you're looking to keep the channel open for an asynchronous response, the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener requires <return true;> to be added to the onMessage event handler.. Can fromEventPattern handle this?